# How to build a react native dynamic library for a specific ios version?

Tags: ios, performance, react-native, performance-testing, react-native-cli

I want to inspect my app and do some CPU profiling and according to this video https://youtu.be/0MlT74erp60, I am supposed to build a react native dynamic library for a specific iOS version. I have managed to build a library and link it through Xcode but can't figure out the command for how to build it for a "specific" ios version.

Any help is much appreciated.